# Should noexcept be used on functions exposed by a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll

I know from tedious experience that it's a bad idea to pass C++ objects across a shared library boundary (specifically that of a DLL, in my case), as allocating memory on the library's heap and freeing it when operating with a different (eg. application) heap will cause undefined behaviour and a lot of headaches. Because of this, I've been careful to design my library interface using plain types and no STL classes, while still making use of C++ niceties where it's reasonable to do so (eg. exposing library functions via a pure virtual interface is OK as far as I know).

However, given the heap allocation limitations above, I gather that it is also not a good idea to throw exceptions across a library boundary for the same reason. Completely disabling exception use within the library is not an option for me since certain internal third-party libraries use them, so I've been considering what my approach should be.

I've been choosing to mark all my library interface functions as `noexcept`, based on the reasoning that:

1. Exceptions should not be used on functions that constitute a shared library boundary, so this basically equates a boundary function with a `noexcept` function.
2. If for some reason an exception is not caught within the library and propagates to a boundary function, having the program terminate due to a `noexcept` violation is likely to be preferable to undefined behaviour occurring. Sure, terminating the user's application is bad, and measures should be taken to avoid this at all costs, but a "clean" termination will be much easier to identify than cross-heap memory operation failures.

Is this a reasonable assessment? Are there best practices regarding exceptions when writing a shared library?

---

EDIT: Based on discussions in the comments, I'd like to clarify an additional two points:

1. Am I correct in thinking that the presence or absence of `noexcept` on an external function signature should not affect the library user's code?

As far as I understand, the presence or absence of `noexcept` should only affect the behaviour of the internals of the function that is marked `noexcept`, ie. something like:

```
// Without noexcept:
void MyFunction()
{
    // Do some things
}

// With noexcept, it's as if the function was written:
void MyFunction() noexcept
{
    try
    {
        // Do some things
    }
    catch ( ... )
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Therefore, regardless of whether `noexcept` exists on a function signature, the *caller* of the function should not have to treat it any differently, and therefore it should not affect whether or not the function is safe to call across a library boundary.

2. Is a C++ interface that uses C-style behaviour (ie. C data types, calling conventions, etc.) equivalent in cross-ABI safety as a "pure C" interface (ie. one that a C compiler would accept)?

If true, and if point 1 is also true, then surely a function like `void MyFunction() noexcept` in C++ is just as safe as a function like `void MyFunction()` in C? Not only this, but would it not in fact be *more* safe, given you have the added guarantee that an exception will not be thrown across the boundary?

Comment: Would it be worth your while adding appropriate `try ... catch(...)` blocks in the functions exported by your DLL? If all *possible* exceptions in a function are caught and handled, then you can (safely?) declare that as `noexcept`.

Comment: It is not possible to pass C++ exceptions across an ABI boundary eg `C++ -> C -> C++` or `C++ -> C++` with different a compiler / compiler setting.  You need to determine if you have ABI boundary.  This applies not just to exceptions but to any of the `std::collection`s and other std objects where the internal representation may be different.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, I think this would be good practice anyway, and would functionally render those calls `noexcept`, but it doesn't really answer the question of whether `noexcept` is recommended or not.

Comment: @RichardCritten This is what I was thinking, especially as I can't know if a user's ABI is the same as the ABI I used to compile the library. This is what makes me think `noexcept` would be better than undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you have an ABI boundary then you are restricted to `C` data types and  cannot allocate memory one side of the ABI boundary and free it in on the other. This ABI issue includes virtual functions as the layout of the vtable (or other mechanism) may be different.

Comment: It is a good idea to pass C++ objects (including exceptions) across a shared library. The bad idea is to assume binary compatibility between separately built C++ components, including pure virtual interfaces. If you want compatibility then you'll need to use plain C interface.

Comment: Point taken about vtables. However, no-one's addressed the fundamental question regarding `noexcept` yet.

Comment: @NoodleCollie If you have an ABI boundary then the `noexcept` question is irrelevant as the other problems are much larger and restrict you to a pure `C` interface (where you can't use `noexcept`),  If you don't have an ABI boundary then the question is irrelevant.

Comment: There's a difference between "an interface using C types" vs. "a pure C interface" though, right? I'm still targeting C++ rather than C, so as long as the data that passes across the boundary is comprised of basic types and the C++ features don't affect how the functions are called, I should be OK? Or am I wrong? I thought the only thing that cared _at runtime_ about `noexcept` was the internals of the library itself.